# CLLocationManager distanceFromLocation: returns -1

Tags: iphone, distance, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use corelocation at the very beginning of my app, to get initial location.

I have delegate method:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    DLog(@"received location data from %f ago, lat/long - %+.6f, %+.6f\nold lat/long %+.6f, %+.6f\nhorizontal accuracy is %f", 
     howRecent, newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude, 
     oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude, 
     newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);

    // check if new update is significantly different from old one.  If it is, then reverse-geocode.
    if ([newLocation respondsToSelector:@selector(distanceFromLocation:)]) {
        DLog(@"distance from old to new location - %f", [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation]);
        if ([newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation] < 1000) {
            // reverse geocode please
            [self stopLocationManager];
        }
    }

    else if ([newLocation respondsToSelector:@selector(getDistanceFrom:)]){
        DLog(@"distance from old to new location - %f", [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation]);
        if ([newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation] < 1000) {
            // reverse geocode please
            [self stopLocationManager];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the log output:

```
... -[AppHelper locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] received location data from -13.261873 ago, lat/long - +37.705413, -121.866296
old lat/long +0.000000, +0.000000
horizontal accuracy is 1982.000000
... -[AppHelper locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] distance from old to new location - -1.000000
```

Any idea why initial distance calculation from newlocation to oldlocation of (0,0) is yielding -1 result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the distance is -1, because the old location (0,0) is invalid. I would ignore the first distance (-1) and wait for the next one.

To me it makes perfect sense that the first location can't have an old location.

Comment: errors were misleading, because 0,0 is actually a valid location.. I checked out googlemaps, it's somewhat west of african continent :(  so, I tried to ignore if lat/long were equal to 0, but this didn't work if (!(oldLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.0 && oldLocation.coordinate.longitude == 0.0) always returns zero haha.  Anyway, seems to be something wrong when you call for properties on nil object..  I think if oldlocation is actually a valid object at 0,0, calculation works fine.

Comment: Yeah sure, but it seems unlikely that you've move between lat/long +0.000000, +0.000000 and lat/long - +37.705413, -121.866296 without getting any updates in between, so I still think ignoring the first distance is the way to go. :P

Comment: If you call methods on a nil object it always returns 0.

Comment: Yeah, it's highly unlikely, so I agree with your answer for 99.9% cases.  I'm just OCD when it comes to my code being correct all the time though.  Thanks for your comments!

Comment: re: method on nil object returning 0 - yep that's what i understand, but this is the weird part:  oldLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.0 returns YES, and oldLocation.coordinate.longitude == 0.0 returns YES also in separate test.. but if I put them together, as in !(oldLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.0 && oldLocation.coordinate.longitude == 0.0), this will return YES instead of NO <-- what's going on here? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, second time I'm answering my own question.. sorry I didn't debug enough i guess!

So here's what's happening - when delegate is called first time, it looks like oldLocation can be called with nil.

Thus, distanceFromLocation: is called with nil argument, and returning -1 as some sort of error code.

Anyway, I am now just adding a check to see if oldlocation is nil, and ignore that update for second one.

Would have been nice if distanceFromLocation: actually fires an assertion of some sort when called with nil argument, instead of cryptic -1 error code!  :D